# Google maps v3 decode polygon(s) from MySQL database

Tags: mysql, xml, google-maps, polygon, decode

I would like to draw one or more polygons which are saved encoded in the MySQL database. I've based my code on the known bermudatriangle script [example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/polygon-arrays). The XML from "polygon_xml.php" is OK. For now, there's only 1 encoded coordinate in the database. At: `//alert1(decodedPolygon);` the coordinates are shown, but at `//alert2(decodedPolygon);` it's not. It has something to do with the array `decodedPolygon` I guess. What makes me more confusing is that the polygon does show when I uncomment `//alert2(decodedPolygon);`. Alert2 is empty but after clicking "OK", the polygon is shown on the map!??? Finally I would like to add text to the XML and place it in the infowindow instead of the coordinates.

My 3 encoded coordinates are:

1. {zzfIsjmu@kHuczRrg{NxcsO}t{GtczR
2. a}~cIqcskBu|sEov{OoxNel}AfccMwfzG~q|@nknX}u~GvczR
3. cljkHmfoQl|J{hrV~syGzhrV

I hope somebody can help / explain.

Here's my code so far:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry">
<script>

    var map;
    var infoWindow;
    var decodedPolygon = [];

    function initialize() {
        var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 3,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(49.724479, 17.578125),
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
        };

        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
            mapOptions);

        downloadUrl("polygon_xml.php", function(data) {
            var xml = data.responseXML;
            var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
            //var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
            for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
                var encodedPath = markers[i].getAttribute("coords");

                decodedPolygon = google.maps.geometry.encoding.decodePath(encodedPath);

                //alert1(decodedPolygon);
                //bounds.extend(decodedPolygon);
            }
        })

        //alert2(decodedPolygon);
        // Construct the polygon.
        bermudaTriangle = new google.maps.Polygon({
            paths: decodedPolygon,
            strokeColor: '#FF0000',
            strokeOpacity: 0.8,
            strokeWeight: 3,
            fillColor: '#FF0000',
            fillOpacity: 0.35
        });

        bermudaTriangle.setMap(map);

        // Add a listener for the click event.
        google.maps.event.addListener(bermudaTriangle, 'click', showArrays);

        infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    }

    /** @this {google.maps.Polygon} */
    function showArrays(event) {

        // Since this polygon has only one path, we can call getPath()
        // to return the MVCArray of LatLngs.
        var vertices = this.getPath();

        var contentString = '<b>Bermuda Triangle polygon</b><br>' +
            'Clicked location: <br>' + event.latLng.lat() + ',' + event.latLng.lng() +
            '<br>';

        // Iterate over the vertices.
        for (var i = 0; i < vertices.getLength(); i++) {
            var xy = vertices.getAt(i);
            contentString += '<br>' + 'Coordinate ' + i + ':<br>' + xy.lat() + ',' +
                xy.lng();
        }

        // Replace the info window's content and position.
        infoWindow.setContent(contentString);
        infoWindow.setPosition(event.latLng);

        infoWindow.open(map);
    }

    function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
        var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
            new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
            new XMLHttpRequest;

        request.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (request.readyState == 4) {
                request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
                callback(request, request.status);
            }
        };

        request.open('GET', url, true);
        request.send(null);
    }

    function doNothing() {}

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
```

```
<body>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
```

Comment: What does your XML look like?  Can you provide a sample?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`downloadUrl` is asynchronous, you need to use the data returned inside the callback routine.  Right now, the `bermudaTriangle` polygon is constructed before the data is returned (outside of the callback function).

```
function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
      zoom: 3,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(49.724479, 17.578125),
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
  };

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
      mapOptions);

  downloadUrl("polygon_xml.php", function(data) {
    var xml = data.responseXML;
    var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
      for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
        var encodedPath = markers[i].getAttribute("coords");

        var decodedPolygon = google.maps.geometry.encoding.decodePath(encodedPath);
        for (var j = 0; j < decodedPolygon.length; j++) {
          bounds.extend(decodedPolygon[j]);
        }
        // Construct the polygon.
        var bermudaTriangle = new google.maps.Polygon({
            paths: decodedPolygon,
            strokeColor: '#FF0000',
            strokeOpacity: 0.8,
            strokeWeight: 3,
            fillColor: '#FF0000',
            fillOpacity: 0.35
        });

        bermudaTriangle.setMap(map);

        // Add a listener for the click event.
        google.maps.event.addListener(bermudaTriangle, 'click', showArrays);

      }
      map.fitBounds(bounds);
    })

    infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
}
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oomxLg9e/1/)

Comment: Thank you so much for explaining me. I added 2 extra encoded polygons to the database, but only one is shown on the map. How can I show all the polygons on the map? Loop the bermudaTriangle?

Comment: That would be a different question.  When you ask that please be sure to provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue. If this answered your original question, please [accept it](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Comment: Well, the code above is for drawing one polygon. I asked, "one or more polygons". After spending 2 hours I can't get it done. I've looked for examples on your website but I'm too rookie to get it done myself. Can you add the code to see show multiple polygons please? That shouldn't be difficult for you. Doing my best...

Comment: You didn't provide _any_ encoded polygon data.  Provide some samples.

Comment: Please don't post code in the comments (it is really hard to read). Update your question with the requested information.

Comment: Updated my answer, there was a bug (reused i in the inner loop)

Comment: Thank you so much. Where is your "donate" button? Much appreciated!!! How can I contact you? No contact info on your website?